# jQuery UI bounce effect aligns elements left in Firefox and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

There is an issue with JQuery UI's bounce effect in both Firefox and IE8 or lower. IE9, Chrome, and Safari render the bounce effect properly. Any ideas what is causing this?

The problem is exhibited in Firefox and Chrome. The popup asks if you received an invitation. In Firefox/IE8 the box jumps to the left-hand side when it bounces.

Here is the jQuery that is running the bounce:

```
            if ($.readCookie('noticehidden') == null)
            {
                $('#notice').show('drop', { direction: 'left' }, 2000)
                .data('bounceinterval', setInterval(function ()
                {
                    $('#notice').effect("bounce", { times: 3, distance: 10 }, 300);
                }, 5000));
                $('#dismissnotice').click(function (e)
                {
                    clearInterval($('#notice').data('bounceinterval'));
                    $('#notice').hide('drop', { direction: 'right' }, 2000);
                    $.setCookie('noticehidden', 'true', { duration: 365 });
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            }
```

I am using jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bounce effect applies this style to the element:

```
element.style {
    bottom: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
}
```

Firefox disregards `margin:auto` in favor of `left:0`.
This fixed the problem:

```
#notice {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

And for variable-width box:

```
#notice-container {
  text-align: center;
}

#notice {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT:** For anyone that uses this answer I wanted to add a couple minor tweaks that made it work.

First

```
    #notice-container
    {
      text-align: center;
      display: none; /*Add this to make the parent invisible until the show effect is used.*/
    }
```

Next, the above JQuery in the question should be modified to use the parent container, not the centered child.

```
$('#notice-container').show('drop', { direction: 'right' }, 2000);
$('#notice-container').effect('bounce', { times: 3, distance: 10 }, 300);
// etc...
```

Comment: Yeah, this would just suck if I had a variable width container.

Comment: @Chevex well, then you would just set display:inline-block and apply text-align:center to the container.

Comment: Ouch, that actually made the issue start happening in all browsers :/

Comment: Yep, worked for me on a simplified example, but didn't work on your site. Well, I guess $('#notice').css('margin-left': parentWidth - noticeWidth/2) is programmer's best friend here then.

Comment: This works but requires one additional tweak. All effect operations have to be performed on the parent (#notice-container), not the centered child (#notice). Uploading changes now so you can see it in action :)

Comment: True, didn't think about doing it with jquery and calculating the left margin. That would work too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "All effect operations have to be performed on the parent" - clever idea. It works fine now.