# jQuery "bounce" effect on center-aligned block elements aligns them left in Firefox and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My goal is to have several images displayed horizontally centered within a div which is also horizontally centered within a wrapper.  I can do this, but when I invoke jQuery's "bounce" effect on the images, they align left.

I have fiddled around for ages and can't get them to remain centered while they bounce.

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/vX3gz/2

I'm using the latest Firefox on Win7.

Comment: no repo in Chrome 21. What browser are you using? No repo in IE 9, but can confirm behavior in IE 8.

Comment: I can see problematic effect in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE (all on Win7).

Comment: It works fine for me, too, but I'm also using Chrome 21.

Comment: looks fine in Chrome and IE9, but in Firefox they are left while bouncing then snap to middle, at least for me

Comment: Works in Chrome btw! Not in Firefox

Comment: OK, so the problem is in Firefox. Any ideas welcome. Thanks.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080902/jquery-ui-bounce-effect

Comment: @c_kick That didn't work for me. Adding margin-left does work, but it assumes my content isn't variable width. Also the images then become left-aligned after the margin! Arrrrrrrgh. I'm going to use tables soon.

Comment: Tables? Noooooooooooo ;-) I'll pry around in your fiddle tomorrow and see what I can come up with

Comment: I wonder if you'd be more successful using css3 to do this? Isn't there a property that does something to that effect?

Comment: @imakeitpretty you could use [animate](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/bouncing-ball-animation/); in particular [float](http://codepen.io/simurai/pen/floating-buttons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the images are "jumping" left is because bounce is adding a couple of `div` elements with inline styles that set `margin: 0`.

So a fairly simple work around would be to override this in your own CSS:

```
#thin > div {
    margin: 0 auto !important;   
}
```

**Note** I am usually against using `!important` but since you are using it to override an inline style I think that it is acceptable.

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vX3gz/33/**

Comment: *hangs head in shame*... that's a lot shorter than my abomination, and an obvious solution once you 'see it'. Nice one!

Comment: Awesome. Shows that one needs to be mindful of what jQuery is actually doing to your markup. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think I've solved it. Not in the way that I like it (with CSS), and perhaps a bit overkill, but it works nonetheless. The problem is indeed the left margin, and you really don't want to set that when dealing with variable content that you want to center. Also: I noticed Safari (for Windows) has the same problem.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/tuu4Q/

So what I did is write a custom BounceMe() function, to which you pass the element(s) to be bounced. What it does:

1. checks if we're in Firefox or Safari and if not: regular bounce (skips steps below)
2. get the current (actual) left offset of the element
3. apply that offset to the element as a margin-left
4. bounce it
5. reset the margin left to auto

Also, it sets a 'bouncing' flag on the element, to prevent the function from bouncing something that is already bouncing.

**Important** all elements should get

```
position: relative;
```

or the offset calculations will be off.

The jQuery:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());//to prevent Chrome from being detected as safari  

function BounceMe($this) {
    if($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.safari && !$.browser.chrome){
        if (!$this.data('bouncing')) {
            $this.each(function(){ //run on each img
                $pos = $(this).position(); // get position of image
                $(this).css({marginLeft: $pos.left}); //'hard' set the margin left
            });

            $this.data('bouncing', true).effect("bounce", function(){
                $this.css({marginLeft: 'auto'}) //reset the margin left after animation
                    .data('bouncing', false);
            });
        } else {
            //images are still animating, do nothing
        }
    } else {
        //no Firefox or Safari? No problem, do a regular bounce.
        $this.stop().effect("bounce");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    BounceMe($("img")); //bounce on pageload

    $("#bounce").click(function() {
        BounceMe($("img")); //bounce on click on link
    });
});
```

You can rewrite the function to an .extend() so it can be chained like the regular Bounce().

Comment: A lot of very useful techniques in here. Thank you for all your time! :)