# JQuery bounce is jumping out of place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bounce

I'm trying to use the jQuery UI bounce effect on a button positioned with css "left" on mouseover. It seems to work, however if you mouse over back and forth over it a few times it moves out of place and sticks to the left. I'm not really sure why it's doing this. Here's my code: http://jsbin.com/afoyiz/1/edit

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080902/jquery-ui-bounce-effect-aligns-elements-left-in-firefox-and-ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your css definition

```
left: 20%
```

seems to be getting overridden. Possibly as a result of `bounce` issuing `left: 0` and then not properly caching the previous value of `left`. What ensues is `left: 0` being cached as the proper value and the element getting shot to the left when all is said and done.

What I would suggest is locking this functionality. This will prevent the error, and also will prevent the gaming of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lockMouseover;
  $("#button").mouseover(function(){
    if( typeof lockMouseover == "undefined" ){
     $("#button").effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 300 );
      lockMouseover = setTimeout( function(){ var un; lockMouseover = un;}, 950 );
    }
  });
```

});

I tested this on your jsbin and it worked.

Comment: Awesome thanks i added this in and it works sweet as sugar. Funny how just a few characters can make all the difference!